# phpmyadmin navigation panel tree shows databases instead of tables

Tags: phpmyadmin

Not sure what's going on, but while I was working in phpmyadmin today the tree in the navigation panel on the left started listing the databases under each database instead of that database's tables.

[screenshot showing phpmyadmin nav panel issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T10bd.png)

I think this started soon or right after I did a SELECT on information_schema.columns using the SQL tab while I was browsing a table in the ld_data database, but it seems unlikely this caused the problem.

I already tried clearing cache and cookies, and the same issue happens using a different browser.

Answer (score 0):

This was a [bug](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/17308) that briefly appeared in phpMyAdmin releases 4.9.8, 4.9.9, and 5.1.2. It was fixed starting with 4.9.10 and 5.1.3, so you can upgrade to the latest version for the fix.

Comment: Unfortunately this issue is happening with 5.1.3. This is my web hosting provider's phpmyadmin, and it says: "5.1.3 (up to date)
Git revision: 07d16df from NFSN-STABLE branch,
committed on Feb 11, 2022 at 04:40 PM by jdw